# Showing that $\varepsilon_k$ make a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

With $\mathbb{C}^n := \{(a_0, \dots, a_{n-1}) : a_j \in \mathbb{C}\}$ and

$$\varepsilon_k = (1, \zeta^k, \dots, \zeta^{(n-1)k})/\sqrt{n}$$

where $\zeta = e^{2\pi i / n}$, show that $\varepsilon_0, \dots, \varepsilon_{n-1}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$

I believe we are dealing with an arbitrary inner product here.EDIT: Nope, looks like it's the standard one. This makes the rest of the problem considerably easier, so I think I've got it from here. Thanks. This professor is really making me lose my mind.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the $\epsilon_k$'s to form an orthonormal system, we need that when we take the inner product $\langle \epsilon_j, \epsilon_k \rangle$ we get $1$ if $j=k$ and we get $0$ otherwise. So let's check this:
$$
\langle \epsilon_j, \epsilon_k \rangle = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \zeta^{ji} \overline{\zeta^{ki}} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \zeta^{(j-k)i}
= \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 1 = 1, & j=k,\\
\frac{1}{n} \left( \textrm{sum of $n^{th}$ roots of unity} \right) = 0, & j \not= k.
\end{cases}
$$
Next, one way to see that they are linearly independent is to put all of the vectors $\epsilon_0,\ldots,\epsilon_{n-1}$ into a matrix and show that its determinant is nonzero. Computing this determinant will be quite easy since you will get a [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).

Comment: is the statement wrong when $\langle \rangle$ is arbitrary? Applying the standard inner product simplifies things drastically, but throughout the notes before we are always using arbitrary inner products and it would be absolutely criminal of my professor if he wants us to use the standard one here and expecting us to realize without telling us when we've literally only used arbitrary ones. As you can tell, I'm a little bit frustrated at this professor right now.

Comment: I assumed that you were discussing the standard Hermitian inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$, since a set is orthonormal for a specific choice of inner product. Moreover, it is not true that your basis $\epsilon_0,\ldots,\epsilon_{n-1}$ (or any basis, for that matter) forms an orthonormal set with respect to every inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Consequently, it's probably safe to assume you can use the standard Hermitian inner product.

Comment: Ugh. Thanks, msteve. I've got some angry emails to write...